# Create converging list of integers

Tags: python, function

I need to create a converging list of integers that, for any given length, will be ordered:

largest, smallest, second largest,second smallest,third largest,third smallest...

until we run out of numbers.

E.g.

```
def converging_list(val):
   lst = some clever function
   return lst

converging_list(7)
Output: [7,0,6,1,5,2,4,3]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Some googling gets you far: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rearrange-array-order-smallest-largest-2nd-smallest-2nd-largest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-recursive solution:

```
def converging_list(val):
    i = 0
    j = val
    lst = []
    while j > i:
        lst.append(j)
        lst.append(i)
        i += 1
        j -= 1
    if val % 2 == 0: lst.append(i)
    return lst

print(converging_list(7))
```

prints

```
[7, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive solution, using `yield`:

```
def converging_list(val, end=0):
    if val >= end:
        yield val
        yield end
        yield from converging_list(val-1, end+1)

>>> list(converging_list(7))
[7, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

If you don't want to call `list` outside the function, just change it to `helper` function:

```
def converging_list(val):
    def _helper(val, end=0):
        if val >= end:
            yield val
            yield end
            yield from _helper(val-1, end+1)
    return list(_helper(val))

>>> converging_list(7)
[7, 0, 6, 1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

This can be made more general, i.e., to account for negative values:

```
def converging_list(val):
    def _helper(val, end=0):
        sign = 1 if val>0 else -1
        if val*sign >= end*sign:
            yield val
            yield end
            yield from _helper(val-1*sign, end+1*sign)
    return list(_helper(val))

>>> converging_list(-7)
[-7, 0, -6, -1, -5, -2, -4, -3]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try a while loop on the input elements while it length is not zero.
In the loop I would compute themin and max of the current list, add the two the the output list, and remove them from the current list.
But this assumes that there are no duplicates is it the case ?

Comment: In this case I am providing the desired length of the list, not the list itself. So no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

The index is used to prevent the calculations from continuing past the half way point.

```
def converging_list(val):
    listzip = zip(range(val//2+1),reversed(range(val+1)),range(val))
    lst     = sum(([a, b] for i, a, b in listzip), [])[:val+1]
    return lst
```